# How to open a linux directory from browser using php?

Tags: php, directory, exec, system, nautilus

i am new to php, and i would like to know how to open a directory using php.
i've tried the following codes, but nothing happened

```
 exec('nautilus /home/');
 exec('sudo nautilus /home/');
 $command='nautilus /home/';
 system($command);
```

i am using Centos 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Try with opendir() php function.

Comment: i need to pop out a window (just like windows explorer) with the contents of directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try pcmanfm /home it will open a Directory in Linux. or Explorer in Windows